# Is there a way to calculate the probability of drawing X+ > y% of time given X-

Tags: probability, bayesian, binomial-distribution, conditional-probability

Say I have a bag with 10 balls (either red or blue), and I know that there are 8 balls that are red. How do I calculate the probability of drawing a a red ball $>75\%$ of the time if the first ball I picked without replacements is red? Hope this is clear. Thanks!

Comment: To what "time" do you refer?  Does the 75% include the first ball you drew?  Do you mean you know *exactly* eight balls are red or that you know there exist eight red balls in the bag?

Comment: thanks your question was enough to answer my original question.  I was not thinking straight by not defining time correctly.